# How difficult would it be to make a simple 3D graphics engine in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I'm interested in 3D games, and would like to learn more about how their graphics work. I want to try to make a simple graphics engine, in C++, for the experience. How much would I need to know? I'm a self-taught amateur in high school, can I realistically do it?

By 'simple' I mean untextured, single color planes, without lighting and things like that. And, at least initially, I don't want to make an actual game with moving objects, just render a simple environment.

Comment: Not simple, but do-able.  To guess at how hard, I'd have to be familiar with your current skill with C++, algebra, and linear algebra. Recommend a lot of research.

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with graphics. Making a graphic engine in C++ will likely to be exactly the same level of comlexity as making the same engine in Java or C#. Majority of stuff would be handled by GPU anyways.

Comment: @SergeyA this is true, but if OP wants to get experience in C++, it'a hard to do it in Java and C#.

Comment: I guess it wasn't really necessary to specify C++, I just did because it was the language I know. KostasRim basically gave me the information I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider many things.

First of all you have to be familiar with linear algebra. It is like the holy triad of computer graphics.

Next do you want to target smartphones ? Then the api to consider is openGLes.

For desktop you have a choice. Do you need your engine to be cross platform? Then your best pick is openGL. If you target is only windows you could try direct3d (which i do not recommend, it is not as user friendly as openGL).

Now back to programming. How good are you with c++ ? Do you know how to work with classes and object oriented programming ? If yes you should also consider design patterns for your engine. A good pattern to start with is the model-view-controller(MVC in short).

You have to do a lot research and be patient. You will get there eventually!

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with classes, and know algebra, so I'll start off learning openGL!

Comment: Good luck you have many things to learn !!!